# how to use echo copy with text box with orginal file name

Tags: php, file-upload

Steps of this script.

1. Insert link in text box (like rapidleech) but here I have 2 text box
2. Upload files via echo copy (remote link, my server) (This doesn't work)
3. Print files' HTML info in a textbox (I think here I have an error)

note - Just image information important

note - How can get orginal filename and save on server?

### HTML

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart">
<label for="file">thumb link : </label>
<input type="text" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<label for="file2">image link : </label>
<input type="text" name="file2" id="file2" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
define ( 'IMAGE_DIR', 'img/' );
define ( 'THUMB_DIR', 'thumb/' );
$thumblink = "file1";
$imglink = "file2";
$printhtml = "printhtml";
$filesize = "size";
$filesizelimit = "limit";
$printtxt = "<center><img src=\"{$thumblink}\"/><br/>
            <a href=\"{$imglink}\" target=\"_blank\">download image</a> /
            {$filesize} <br/></center>";
// here is dont work show error
// error   syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
echo copy("{$thumblink}", THUMB_DIR . '["name"]');
echo copy("{$imglink}", IMAGE_DIR . '["name"]');
//

if ((($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file2"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file2"]["size"] < 2000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file2"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file2"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file2"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file2"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file2"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "thumb in: " . $_FILES["file1"][THUMB_DIR];
    echo "image in: " . $_FILES["file2"][IMAGE_DIR];


    echo "<center><img src=\"{$thumblink}\"/><br/>
            <a href=\"{$imglink}\" target=\"_blank\">download image</a> /
             {$filesize} <br/></center>";
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: your `THUMB_DIR` isn't an array. so you can't call `THUMB_DIR["name"]` - either way you should escape quotes in line like this - `"THUMB_DIR["name"]"`. also copy() will echo 1 on success and 0 on false

Answer (score 0):

This can't work:

```
echo print "<center>...";
```

You've gotta chose :P Either echo, or print :) Or else, it will echo "..." followed by a 1 if print() returns TRUE. Is that what you are looking for ?

Also:

```
echo copy("{$thumblink}","THUMB_DIR["name"]");
echo copy("{$imglink}","IMAGE_DIR["name"]");
```

Notice how the quotes get in the way of each other ? And THUMB_DIR & IMAGE_DIR are constants, and not arrays. What do you want do here exactly ?

Also, copy() returns a boolean value. Why echo it ? It will show nothing if copy() returns FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

PHP constants cannot be inserted into a string like that - PHP has no way to know that you're using a constant, and not just some text that happens to look like a constant:

Note the changes:

```
echo copy("{$thumblink}", THUMB_DIR . '["name"]');

echo "image in: " . $_FILES["file2"][IMAGE_DIR];
```

Comment: hi i edit and test and i get erros PHP Warning:  copy(file1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\upload\upload_file.php on line 14
PHP Warning:  copy(file2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\upload\upload_file.php on line 15
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\upload\upload_file.php on line 18
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\upload\upload_file.php on line 19
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php\upload\upload_file.php on line 20

Comment: yes. because your THUMB_DIR isn't an array with index `name` - you should create it first

Answer (score 0):

please change your `define` to:

```
$IMAGE = array('IMAGE_DIR' => 'img/',
        'THUMB_DIR' => 'thumb/');
```

Then

```
$new_file_name = "new.gif";
    echo copy("{$thumblink}", $IMAGE['THUMB_DIR']$new_file_name);
    echo copy("{$imglink}", $IMAGE['IMAGE_DIR'].$new_file_name);
```

still don't understand why should you echo these?..

you also need to change original file name:

```
$imglink = "file2.gif";
```

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' on line 3 - your $IMAGE = array

Comment: i mean orginal file link is http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo101.png and name is nav_logo101.png i want save with same name on server

Comment: sorry `'IMAGE_DIR' = > 'img/'` should be `'IMAGE_DIR' => 'img/'`. then use original name for saved file